# Separate multiple query row results?

Tags: php, mysql

The mysql query result can have 1 or 2 rows with results. How would I separate them?

```
$bio = mysql_query("SELECT *, FROM soc_meminfo 
                    WHERE m_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($en['id'])."'"); 
#                               
if (mysql_num_rows($bio) == 0) call404();
$line = mysql_fetch_assoc($bio);
foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
        $en['b'.$key] = str_replace("\n",'<br/>',stripslashes($value));
        }
```

Comment: separate them from each other? what is your desired output?

Comment: @johntotetwoo there are multiple rows with the same m_id so I need to separate the results by row results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($bio)) { ... }
```

Also your sql should be `SELECT * FROM soc_meminfo`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($bio)){
 foreach ($row as $value){
  echo $value;
 }
 echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand it, but try this.

```
$bio = mysql_query("SELECT *, FROM soc_meminfo 
                    WHERE m_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($en['id'])."'"); 
#                               
if (mysql_num_rows($bio) == 0) call404();
$line = mysql_fetch_assoc($bio);
foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
      $en['b'.$key][] = str_replace("\n",'<br/>',stripslashes($value));
}
```